# stopwatch listview dynamically update- android

Tags: java, android

I currently have a list view where each item represents the current time elapsed. What i would like to do is to every time the user clicks the Lap button, it adds the current stopwatch time to the list. When i run it and press lap nothing happens. I set it up like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
           myList.setAdapter(adapter);
           final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
           final ImageButton buttonLap = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.lap);

           buttonLap.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String s = "" + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase());
               list.add(s);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

           }});
     }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
12-14 09:46:13.557: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to dynamically update the list.  What does it do instead?

Comment: is that the entire `OnCreate`? where's the `ListView` to which `adapter` is connected to?

Comment: ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

must come **after**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**inside** `OnCreate`

Comment: thanks that works! do you know how to format the string so that it comes as time instead of numbers

Comment: why does ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); come after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);?

Comment: @Bob, Becasue you are trying to find a view contained in the layout, but if you haven't inflated the layout, there is nothing to search for an id.  As for the formatting question you should post a separate question for that, as it is totally unrelated to the issue of this question.

Comment: just asking i really dont need to know but it will be benebicial

Comment: for the time format string, you can replace `s` with: `String s = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase());`

Comment: that doesnt work. it comes as 26:28 when its supposed to say :03

Comment: you wanted to have it come as "time instead of numbers" so i assumed that you wanted `00:00` format. the rest is for you to fine-tune yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
   ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You are calling that before you set the content view, so you are getting a null and then you are trying to use it.  You need to move that to your `onCreate` method after you use `setContentView`.